HHL eigenvalue inversion and further inverse QPE
Reading the paper (arXiv) about HHL I misunderstood the following points:
$$|{x}\rangle = A^{-1} \cdot |b\rangle = \sum^{2^nb-1}_{i=0}\lambda_i^{-1}b_i|u_i\rangle$$

How do we inverse the eigenvalues? The only option between forward and inverse QPE (which is uncomputation, not eigenvalue inversion) is operation on the ancilla qubit.

Why do we exactly need this manipulation with controlled rotation of the ancilla? As I understood, this step shows the correctness of the eigenvalue computation: the total sum of angles should be equal to $\pi$ - am I right?

For me it seems like we do forward QPE -> rotate ancilla -> compute inverse QPE. Why anything should be changed in QPE if all idea is to do two steps related to $|b\rangle$ effect of which are opposite to each other? Shouldn't $|b\rangle$ remain the same?


upd: based on the same paper, user should have a priori information about the relation of the eigenvalues. This relation allows to chose a proper angle for ancilla rotation. Do I understand this point correct?
upd 2: based on another paper the inverted matrix $A^{-1}$ appears immediately after inverse QPE. But is this true? Circuit from paper is attached below:


I assume you're mentioning about the equation (47) with upd's question. You're right, this paper uses the eigenvalues to implement $\theta$(c) function. If c is encoded eigenvalues then it conducts a rotation.


The forward QPE puts the eigenvalues into the clock register. The phases are now qubits We that can be acted upon.  You can calculate $\lambda^{-1}$ in much the same way as my 1980's-era calculator calculates $1/x$. There is a physical circuit to perform the inversion inside of the calculator; there will be a roughly equivalent circuit to perform the inversion on the qubits. Indeed up to some error you can build a quantum circuit to map $\sum|\lambda\rangle|0\rangle$ to $\sum|\lambda\rangle|\lambda^{-1}\rangle$, or really for any Lipschitz continuous function $f(\lambda)$.

After we perform the inversion, we only then rotate the ancilla.  This rotation is controlled by the inverse of the eigenvalues - by $|\lambda^{-1}\rangle$, not by $|\lambda\rangle$.

We then compute the inverse QPE based on the eigenvalues that we got on step 1 above. But imagine that we haven't measured the ancilla yet - then it can be seen to be entangled with $|b\rangle$ even after uncomputing.


The original HHL paper was mostly silent on how to do the rotation in step 2. Then again, Shor's original paper was mostly silent on how to do the modular exponentiation using repeated squaring. The literature refers to "filter functions" for various functions $f(\lambda)$ that can be done to rotate the ancilla. The filter functions that I've seen need to know the condition number $\kappa$ of the matrix $A$, but they otherwise take $\lambda$ as the input.
Sev Gharibian has used the phrase "eigenvalue surgery" for the above. I think that's a nice and accurate way to describe HHL's inversion process.


do I understand correctly that the part of the inversion circuit is missed in the paper? The ancilla rotation is applied in a wrong way: not to $\lambda^{-1}$ but to $\lambda$
? 3) "We then compute the inverse QPE based on the eigenvalues" or to the inverted eigenvalues?


As for the third question, I was mistaken in my initial posting which implied that we insert $|\lambda^{-1}\rangle$ by running the QPE backwards.  But we only use $|\lambda^{-1}\rangle$ (a vector) to do the controlled rotation of the ancilla by the appropriate angle (a scalar). So we kick back $|\lambda\rangle$ with the inverse QPE, after we've rotated the ancilla to put a normalized $\lambda^{-1}$ into the amplitudes.

ok, but how do we invert the eigenvalue? In c register eigenvalue is stored in binary form. From each qubit we do a control rotation to ancilla - and c registers is not changed here. No phase kickback or any other effect that changes register. How $\lambda$ turns into $\lambda^{-1}$?
